# stomp.Connection() timeout option not working as expected

Tags: python, sockets, activemq-classic, stomp

## Summary

An unexpected disconnection issue with `stomp.Connection(timeout=5)`, where connections terminate after 5 seconds despite a successful initial connection, contrasting with Python socket behavior which maintains the connection post-timeout.

## Problem

I'm running `activeMQ` in localhost, and I confirmed connection are successfully established.

If I give `stomp.Connection()` a timeout option as an argument, to my knowledge, timeout option would only affects only when initial connection. For example, if I use `stomp.Connection(timeout=5)`, the expected behavior is that an exception will be thrown if connection establishment fails for 5 seconds on the first connection.

However, what I've observed is that the connection is being terminated after 5 seconds even if the connection successfully established and even when activeMQ is still available.

## Code Example

If I run the code below, my expectation is that the timeout option is only applied to the initial connection, so if the connection is made within 5 seconds, the connection should be maintained. However, as you can see in terminal, the connection is disconnected after about 5 seconds. (I think the initial ‘False’ is due to the connection not being fully established yet)

```
import stomp
import time

conn = stomp.Connection(timeout=5)
conn.connect('localhost', 61613)

while True:
    message = "Hello, world!"
    print(f"Sent message: {message}")
    print(conn.is_connected())
    time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

If I write client code that does something similar with the python standard library's socket (server is on), the connection will still be maintained after the timeout has passed.

```
import socket
import time

def client_program():
    host = "localhost"  
    port = 5000

    client_socket = socket.socket()
    client_socket.connect((host, port)) 
    client_socket.settimeout(5)

    while True:
        if client_socket.fileno() == -1:
            print("Connection is closed.")
            break
        else:
            print("Connection is kept preserved.")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_program()
```

[image]

## Suspected problem

There are a couple of possible problems.

- wrong code (really simple code, but where?)
- problem with ActiveMQ
- Issues with TCP keep-alive
- or **Really a bug ????**

Thank you for maintaining a good library. Hope for comments.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure your second script which uses a raw socket provides a valid comparison. First, it doesn't actually complete any messaging protocol handshake which means it will be treated differently than an actual STOMP protocol connection. Second, the broker actually _will_ close the connection in less than a minute if no protocol handshake is completed at which point your script _still_ reports that the connection is valid. Third, [`settimeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) applies to "blocking socket operations" which you are not actually performing.

Comment: Have you tried using STOMP [heart-beating](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Heart-beating)? This is the mechanism defined in the STOMP specification by which connections are to be validated so they can remain open while they are idle.